# Laravel 8: How to redirect user after updatation process

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my forum project and currently I have made a page that users can edit their answers. Here is the form:

```
   <form action="{{ route('update.answer', [$anss->id, $que->id]) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control" rows="7">{{ $ans->answer }}</textarea>
        @error('answer')
            <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                {{ $message }}
            </div>
        @enderror
        <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500 BJadidBold">Update</button>
    </form>
```

And then at the Controller method, I added this:

```
public function updateAnswer(Answer $anss, Question $que)
    {
        $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
           'answer' => 'required'
        ])->validated();

        $answer = Answer::findOrFail($anss);
        $answer->update($validate_data);
    }
```

And here is the route for that:

```
Route::post('questions/{anss}/{que}' , [QuestionController::class, 'updateAnswer'])->name('update.answer');
```

Now I want to redirect user to a url like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/questions/question-slug-example
```

However, by this code, user will redirect to this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/questions/answer_id_example/question-slug-example
```

So how can I do that proerly?

I would really appreciate if you share your idea or suggestion with me on this...

Thanks.

Comment: check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#redirect-routes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect to a POST type route. It has to be of type GET. To redirect you can use:

```
return redirect('/questions/example/example');
```

Comment: I didn't say I want to redirect to a POST method. That route which is included in question is for updating

Comment: Excuse me, I understood that you wanted to redirect to that route. Anyway, you can use 'return redirect' to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If your route type is get and its named route then you can redirect like this

```
return redirect()->route('route_name')->with(['data' => $data]);
```

If your route type is get and you have not specify the name of your route then

```
return redirect('/any_route_url_defined_in_web.php')->with(['data' => $data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After completing the update process, you can use this code to redirect the user.

```
return redirect('redirect url')
```